# python: find closest match of small integer list in a big integer list

Tags: python, list, time-series, match

I have a big list of integer values (~1000 elements in the list).

I have a second smaller list of integers with around 5 elements.

I want to find the closest sub-list of the big list to match the smaller list.

Is that possible with python?

It would be something like this:

```
list 1

list 2
```

Find closest match of `list2` in `list1`.

Comment: *"I want to find the closest sub-list of the big list to match the smaller list"* what does that mean exactly? Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: closest match with respect to which metric: Euclidean distance, L1-distance or something else?

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

You mean:

```
print(max(l,key=lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,x,l2).ratio()))
```

**Demo on some small list:**

```
import difflib
l=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
l2=[1,2,4]
print(max(l,key=lambda x: difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,x,l2).ratio()))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```